# CURL with PHP to Azure

Tags: php, json, azure, curl

How can create one workitem with CURL with PHP:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
"https://dev.azure.com/fernandodomenike/fernando/_apis/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=5.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$post = array(
   'file' => '@' .realpath('azure.json')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'username' . ':' . 'secret');
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json-patch+json';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
  echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

I try execute with command line Windows and work.

Whats is my wrong?

Comment: File upload via @ is a feature from command line cURL client, you have to implement your own code on PHP

Comment: I change the format CURL, but not work.

Answer (score 0):

File upload via @ is a feature from command line cURL client, you have to implement your own code on PHP to do that.

Example:

```
$json = file_get_contents('azure.json');

// Attach JSON string to the POST fields
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Have problem of Security the file_get_contents.